# Remove all the objects with same value on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hello i am new to programming and i have a problem on system in which i am trying to make a Booking system.

I want to remove a chunk of objects with same id from an array while clicking a btn.
Here is an array..

```
array = [
{ id: 1, futsal: "4", time: "06:00 - 09:00", … },
​
{ id: 1, futsal: "4", time: "06:00 - 09:00", … },
​
{ id: 1, futsal: "4", time: "06:00 - 09:00", … },

{ id: 2, futsal: "4", time: "07:00 - 08:00", … },
​
{ id: 2, futsal: "4", time: "07:00 - 07:00", … },
​
{ id: 3, futsal: "4", time: "08:00 - 09:00", … },
​
{ id: 3, futsal: "4", time: "08:00 - 09:00", … },
​
{ id: 3, futsal: "4", time: "08:00 - 09:00", … }]
```

I want to remove all the objects with same id at once i.e either all objects with id=1 or 2...

Comment: What code have you tried?  You need a function that creates another list without the things you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

---

```
const uniqueIds = [];

  const unique = arr.filter(element => {
  const isDuplicate = uniqueIds.includes(element.id);

  if (!isDuplicate) {
    uniqueIds.push(element.id);

    return true;
  }

    return false;
  });

  // ️ 
  console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods for obtaining a filtered object.

```
    { id: 1, futsal: "4", time: "06:00 - 09:00", },
    { id: 1, futsal: "4", time: "06:00 - 09:00", },
    { id: 1, futsal: "4", time: "06:00 - 09:00", },
    { id: 2, futsal: "4", time: "07:00 - 08:00", },
    { id: 2, futsal: "4", time: "07:00 - 07:00", },
    { id: 3, futsal: "4", time: "08:00 - 09:00", },
    { id: 3, futsal: "4", time: "08:00 - 09:00", },
    { id: 3, futsal: "4", time: "08:00 - 09:00", }
];
```

Option first

```
const itemUIds = items.map(o => o.id)
const filteredOption1 = items.filter(({id}, index) => !itemUIds.includes(id, index + 1));
console.log(filteredOption1)
```

Option second

```
const filteredOption2 = Object.values(items.reduce((acc,cur)=>Object.assign(acc,{[cur.id]:cur}),{}));
console.log(filteredOption2)
```

Option third

```
const uniqueItem:any = {};
const filteredOption3 = items.filter(obj => !uniqueItem[obj.id] && (uniqueItem[obj.id] = true));
console.log(filteredOption3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to check with `id` as a unique key then you can use the **ES6** feature to get a unique list of objects by key.

```
newArr = [...new Map(array.map(item => [item["id"], item])).values()]// I am passing `id` as key
```

```js
array = [
{ id: 1, futsal: "4", time: "06:00 - 09:00"},
{ id: 1, futsal: "4", time: "06:00 - 09:00"},
{ id: 1, futsal: "4", time: "06:00 - 09:00"},
{ id: 2, futsal: "4", time: "07:00 - 08:00"},
{ id: 2, futsal: "4", time: "07:00 - 07:00"},
{ id: 3, futsal: "4", time: "08:00 - 09:00"},
{ id: 3, futsal: "4", time: "08:00 - 09:00"},
{ id: 3, futsal: "4", time: "08:00 - 09:00"}]

newArr = [...new Map(array.map(item => [item["id"], item])).values()]

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can [filter an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to make a copy without the unwanted elements:

```js
const array = [
  { id: 1, futsal: "4", time: "06:00 - 09:00" },
  { id: 1, futsal: "4", time: "06:00 - 09:00" },
  { id: 1, futsal: "4", time: "06:00 - 09:00" },
  { id: 2, futsal: "4", time: "07:00 - 08:00" },
  { id: 2, futsal: "4", time: "07:00 - 07:00" },
  { id: 3, futsal: "4", time: "08:00 - 09:00" },
  { id: 3, futsal: "4", time: "08:00 - 09:00" },
  { id: 3, futsal: "4", time: "08:00 - 09:00" }
];

// only items where id is not 2
const filtered = array.filter(item => item.id !== 2);

console.log(filtered);
```